# Difference between short impact and sustained pressure

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity

If I press the wall (with my hand) I feel a little pressure at my hand and I move away from it.

If I hit the wall (lets say using the same amount of energy for total work) I feel pain in my hand.

Why is it? Is it because time of impact is shorter?

Would I move away from the wall in second case if standing on perfectly frictionless ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are pressing against the wall, what you are feeling is the reaction of the wall to the force you are exerting with your muscles; since this force is spread over the area of your hand, the pressure is not very large: no pain.

In contrast, when you hit the wall (say with a closed fist), the force that is exerted is *the force needed to stop the momentum of your fist and arm* - in other words, considering the momentum equation

$$p \Delta v = F \Delta t$$

then you have significant initial momentum ($pv$) in the fist+arm which has to be stopped in a very short time (there is not much elasticity in your arm, so the entire arm has to stop "in an instant" or break). This means that $\Delta t$ is very short, and that $F$ must be correspondingly large. On top of that if you make a fist the area is small, so the pressure ($F/A$) is large. Hence, pain.

In principle, if you were standing on frictionless ground, then you would start to move backwards as you swung a punch at the wall (conservation of momentum - arm moves to wall, you move away). After you hit the wall, the arm stops moving towards the wall (may even move away a little0 but the rest of your body is still moving backwards. So yes, you would move away from the wall.

Comment: "(conservation of momentum - arm moves to wall, you move away)" you mean I move away from wall or arm?

Comment: Both actually. But you move away from the arm faster than from the wall...

Comment: I move away from wall before hitting it? How is that possible?

Comment: As your arm extends, your body moves away, your fist moves towards the wall. Your center of gravity (fist + torso) stays put until you hit the wall (at that point there is a net force on the body+arm system, but not before).

Comment: So my body(torso) moves from the fist perspective but not in actual universe? (Sorry if I messed it up again but it sounds a little tricky) (does it have someting to do with what einstein said- when you move relative to something it moves relative to you)

Comment: Imagine two skaters standing close to each other on the ice. When they hold hands and push each other away, their center of mass doesn't move (no external force on the pair), but the each move relative to the ice, AND relative to each other. Same thing here except the fist is much lighter than another skater. But is has finite mass so to move it towards the wall the person punching must move backwards (when there is NO FRICTION with the ground)

Comment: But with skaters there are 2 forces and when I move just my fist there should be no impact force until it touches something. Does it mean in outer space when I move my fist forward my torso moves backward? Does it matter how fast I move my fist for final velocity change?

Comment: "There are two forces" - for every action there is a reaction. Yes in space when you punch the air your torso briefly moves backwards (but it stops moving once your arm is extended). If you hit the wall harder your arm will have more momentum at the time of impact - and so your torso will be moving faster. Then the wall stops the arm and the net effect is that the gorse keeps moving. More $F\Delta t$ on the system...

Comment: In outer space there is no air. I am asking if my torso would move backward just from moving my hand forward here as well and if velocity of my hand(how fast I punch) matter for how far my torso goes backward ( no walls or anything here)

Comment: Even in space your torso would move backwards just enough to keep the center of gravity in place. A hand of 1 kg  being extended 50 cm requires a torso of 100 kg to move backwards 0.5 cm. and then stop. In reality an arm is not a point mass so the calculation is more complex (not all the mass moves the same distance).